# Вызвать клик по стрелкам input[type="number"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input, события

Есть код

```
<input type="number" class="input-text" value="0" min="0" max="">
```

как вызвать клик по стрелкам внутри input верх и вниз (прибавить и убавить)

нашел код такой:

```
<button id="elem" onclick="alert('Клик');">Автоклик</button>

<script>
  var event = new Event("click");
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```

Но как его применить именно к стрелкам блока input?

в jqvery есть событие .keyup (), но не как не могу разобраться можно ли его сюда применять и главное как?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let [n,r] = [document.getElementById("numPeople"),document.getElementById("result")];

n.addEventListener("input", (e) =>  r.innerHTML += "события input вызвалось <br/>");

n.addEventListener("keyup", (e)  => r.innerHTML += "события keyup вызвалось <br/>");

n.addEventListener("change", (e) =>  r.innerHTML += "события change вызвалось <br/>");
```

```css
input {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<input id="numPeople" type="number" min="0" value="" placeholder="Выбери число" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: ну такое. Скрипт срабатывает при  клике в любом месте инпута. Может сюда подойдет событие `change`? Не пробовали?

Comment: @Дмытрык упс про это не знал сейчас решу

Comment: `change` is working. Только что проверил

Comment: @Дмытрык все работает можете проверить

Comment: ТС же хотел вызвать клик по стрелкам, а не просто обработчики событий добавить.

Comment: @Diskyp ну и вызываетсья же все по клику что ты хочешь ?

Comment: дак не нужно было, чтобы вызывалось по клику, нужно было, чтобы вызывался `dispatchEvent`ом обработчик, записанный на клик. И плюс не просто на инпуте, а на стрелках повышения/понижения значения инпута.

Answer (score 1):

У `input[type=number]` есть методы `stepUp()` и `stepDown()`, которые как раз и отвечают за увеличение/уменьшение значения на величину шага. Эти методы не работают в IE, но ведь там и стрелок нет.

```js
var minus = document.getElementById('minus'),
    plus = document.getElementById('plus'),
    input = document.getElementById('input');
    
minus.addEventListener('click',function(){
  input.stepDown();
});
plus.addEventListener('click',function(){
  input.stepUp();
});
```

```html
<button id="minus">-</button>
<input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="200" step="5" />
<button id="plus">+</button>
```

Или на `JQery`

```js
$('.custom-number button').click(function(){
  if($(this).is('.plus')){
    $(this).siblings('input')[0].stepUp();
  }else{
    $(this).siblings('input')[0].stepDown();
  }
})
```

```css
/*скрыть стандартные стрелки*/
[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-number">
  <button class="minus">-</button>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="200" step="5" />
  <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```